# Angular limitTo not working for ng-model or ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I want to display limited words in the select dropdown list. Cuz text-overflow not working for option. so I want to use limitTo.
I add like

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="tempRequirement" ng-options="item as item.question for item in model.unCompliantRequirementList[model.currentItem] | limitTo: 10"></select>
```

or

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="tempRequirement  | limitTo: 10" ng-options="item as item.question for item in model.unCompliantRequirementList[model.currentItem]"></select>
```

Why they not working?

I tried following instead. But then I cannot trigger loadTheActions(tempRequirement), seems temRequirement is null. Why?

```
<select class="form-control actionplan-dropdown m-t-5" ng-model="tempRequirement">
                                    <option ng-repeat="item in model.unCompliantRequirementList[model.currentItem]" value="item.question"> {{item.question | limitTo: 90}}</option>
            </select>

            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default m-t-10 m-b-10" ng-click="loadTheActions(tempRequirement)" ng-disabled="tempRequirement === undefined"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></button>
```

Thanks for your reply. Solved by adding limit after item.question:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="tempRequirement" ng-options="item as item.question  | limitTo: 10 for item in model.unCompliantRequirementList[model.currentItem]"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `limitTo` will apply to the whole array, not each item within the array. The effect of your first code will be to only show the first 10 items in the dropdown.

Your second example doesn't make sense, you cannot use filters for `ng-model`, because it has to be an *assignable expression*.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting @GregL, You can actually use limitTo with any  valid expression to restrict the actual content that the end user will see in his view.

So, your HTML will infact look something like this :

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="tempRequirement">

    <option  ng-repeat="item in model.unCompliantRequirementList[model.currentItem]" value="{{item.value}}"> {{item.displayValue | limitTo: 10}}</option>

</select>
```

Hope This Helps !!..

Comment: Thanks.But I have a button under this select. I need to trigger ng-click="loadTheActions(tempRequirement)" for this button. But seems tempRequirement not passed to this function so cannot trigger this function correctly.why?

Comment: Posting your prototype code would be more helpful @copiali.. that makes your requirement more understandable.. !!

Comment: The same can be achieved using ng-change on select tag. And secondly, why are you actually passing tempRequirement as a parameter. ?? If it's in your controller, it's accessible in your method too. you can directly access using $scope.tempRequirement